# Java - Send user back to the start?

Tags: java

How will I go about restarting the app if the user asks so.
Here is my code:

```
    System.out.println("Restart?");
    System.out.println("Press 1: Restart");
    System.out.println("Press 2: Finish");
    int restart = sc.nextInt();
    if(restart == 1){

    }
    else if (restart != 1){
        System.out.println("Goodbye..");
    }
```

so if user press 1, the app restarts.. How can i create this?

Comment: restarting app is effectively repeating particular code block in loop in this case, use `do while` loop

Answer (score 1):

Your application sounds like a loop, so lets use one.

```
/* @return true if should restart */
boolean run() {
   System.out.println("Restart?");
   System.out.println("Press 1: Restart");
   System.out.println("Press 2: Finish");
   int restart = sc.nextInt();
   if(restart == 1){
      return true;
   }
   else if (restart != 1){
       System.out.println("Goodbye..");
       return false;
   }
}

while (run());
```

But this is Java, so you might as well do it more object oriented.

```
public class MyRestartable {
    private boolean shouldRestart = true;

    public void run() {
      while(this.shouldRestart) {
        start();
      }
      System.out.println("Goodbye..");
    }

 boolean start() {
       System.out.println("Restart?");
       System.out.println("Press 1: Restart");
       System.out.println("Press 2: Finish");
       this.shouldRestart = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh the joys of object based programming.

```
    void start() {
       System.out.println("Restart?");
       System.out.println("Press 1: Restart");
       System.out.println("Press 2: Finish");
       int restart = sc.nextInt();
       if(restart == 1){
          ***start();***
       }
       else if (restart != 1){
           System.out.println("Goodbye..");
       }
```

Comment: And you're using recursion instead of a simple loop why?

Comment: Why would I use a loop there? Im doing something, im given the option to do it again. I execute a method, im given the option to execute it again. I dont see a loop being useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop, and at the point you want to send the user back to the beginning, use the `break;` command enclosed in an `if` statement to decide whether the user is sent back or continues.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `while` loop would work.

```
public static void Loop(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int loop = 1;

    while(loop == 1){
        System.out.println("Would you like to restart?");
        System.out.println("Press 1 = yes");
        System.out.println("Press 2 = no");
        loop = input.nextInt();
    } 
}
```